# 0 - 100 % GPU spikes when mining [NVIDIA GTX 750 TI]

Tags: mining, gpu-mining, windows, miners

when I start mining using XMR-Stark my GPU (GTX 750 TI) is showing weird 0-100% spikes like this: [Task Manager](https://i.imgur.com/WLtE8Q3.png), [GPU-Z](https://i.imgur.com/29aGaI7.png).

My CPU (i7-4790K) is consistent: [Task Manager](https://i.imgur.com/FeaIm7Z.png).

My hashrate (cpu+gpu) is consistently around [400](https://i.imgur.com/lSipvtG.png) and my GPU temperatures are fine: [HWMonitor](https://i.imgur.com/HYO4q2a.png)

The only solutions I found when googling were to change the settings in the NVIDIA Control Panel to maximum performance but that didn't help.

I am not overclocking my CPU nor my GPU. I am using the latest GPU drivers, latest Windows 10 version, and latest XMR-Stark version.

Does anybody know how to fix this (and possibly increase my hashrate)?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried using a different miner to see if it's causing the problem?

Comment: @JossBird yes, I have tried using a different miner but same result. https://i.imgur.com/KkFNYJy.png

Answer (score 1):

You must open nvidia.txt (a file that xmr-stak creates after running for the first time) and set bsleep and bfactor to something other than the default "0". Try `"bfactor" : 8, "bsleep" :  25,` then restart xmr-stak.

Comment: I tried `"bfactor" : 8, "bsleep" :  25,` but now the GPU usage only goes up to [12% and still has spikes to 0%](https://i.imgur.com/Q7JqQed.png)